# How to eliminate space on .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

Somehow a space was introduced in some of my URL like:

- `/marques-voiture/Ford`
- `/marques-voiture/ Ford`

I attempted to correct that with the following rule on .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/marques-voiture/\s.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule \/marques-voiture\/\s(.*) https://www.example.com/marques-voiture/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Regexp's seem to be correct according to regexp101.com, but `.htaccess` is solemnly ignoring that.

I do have a number of other rules on `.htaccess`, but I do not see a conflict there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `RewriteRule \/marques-voiture\/\s(.*) https://www.example.com/marques-voiture/$1 [R=301,L]`

Your problem is probably the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In per-directory `.htaccess` files the directory-prefix is first removed from the URL-path that is matched. The directory-prefix always *ends* with a slash, so the URL-path that is matched never *starts* with a slash. So, the above rule never matches, not because of the space, but because of the slash prefix!

So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^marques-voiture/\s(.*) https://www.example.com/marques-voiture/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You also don't need the first `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REQUEST_URI` - this is doing the same thing as the `RewriteRule` pattern.

And you don't need to escape slashes in most Apache regex (there are no delimiters).

Make sure you clear your browser cache, as any (erroneous) 301s will have been cached by the browser.